# Flutter animating pattern background image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

in flutter i'm trying to know how can i make animation for background image as pattern. for example: this is simple pattern background image which i would like to make animation like with moving the cloud

[image]

for example:

[image]

by this code we can transfer image by drag, but i would like to make automate this animation not drag:

```
child: new GestureDetector(
  child: new Container(
    height: 80.0,
    child: new Transform.translate(
      offset: new Offset(foo, 0.0),
      child: new Image.asset("resources/scale.png"),
    ),
  ),
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (d) { 
    if(d.primaryDelta >= 1.0 || d.primaryDelta <= - 1.0)
    {
      //print(d.primaryDelta); 
      setState(() {
        foo += d.primaryDelta;
      });
    }
  },
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore [this implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HFDkXqbfJY) that I've found in YouTube. Try to explore the following widgets for image display and movement:

> 1. Stack Widget
> 2. AnimatedPositioned
> 3. BoxDecoration
> 4. AssetImage
> 5. Positioned widget
> 6. DecorationImage Widget
> 7. Timer.Periodic function to change the image position dynamically
> 8. IconButtons to change the state of the widget

And if you want an infinite image you need to implement state management like getx or provider.